# How to include Array (of a struct) in a Struct in Solidity

Tags: struct, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I recently started learning Solidity and I've seen two lecture videos on it and read the official documentation, but I can not seem to get a solution for this. [I've also checked several resources for help but could not find any]

Need: Two `structs` where one references the other (`Reader` struct has a `Book` struct books),
and when a `reader` is created, `books` is empty until they pick up(`pickUp` function) a book. [A constant list of available books is made by me].

What I've tried:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0

contract School {
   struct Book {
      string name;
   }
   Book[2] public books = [Book("we1"), Book("uer")];
    
   struct Reader {
      string name;
      uint booksRead; //for every added book this increments
      Book[] books;
   }

   Reader public readers;
  
   function _createReader(string memory _name) public returns (uint) {
      #some logic
      readers.push(Reader("Freddie", 0, books[0])); 
      uint256 readerID = readers.length - 1;
      return readerID;
      
   }


}
```

Error (doesn't compile): `TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from struct School.Book storage ref to struct School.Book memory[] memory requested.`

I couldn't make sense of this error.

Expected output:

Reader 1 (upon creation): `"Fred", 0, [] //name Fred, booksRead 0, empty list of books`

Reader 1 (upon Updating): `"Fred", 2, [Book("SomeBookI"), ("SomeBookII")]`

Answer (score 0):

Since no one pitched in yet, I'll offer my two cents. First, I'd make sure the `readers` state variable is an array (since you seem to be using it as such), like so:

```
Reader[] public readers;
```

Next, check the following statement:

```
readers.push(Reader("Freddie", 0, books[0]));
```

If you look at the `Reader` struct, the final parameter, `books`, is an array, yet you're passing in a `Book` instance.

To fix this, you'll need to create a new array and pass it in. Since arrays are reference types, you'll also need to specify a [data location](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/types.html#data-location). Judging by your code, you want this array to be dynamic and available throughout the smart contract, so `storage` is the only option. Unfortunately, doing this within the `_createReader` function is [anything but pragmatic](https://blog.b9lab.com/storage-pointers-in-solidity-7dcfaa536089), and any solution I can think of would be hacky at best.

If I were you, I'd rethink the design of the contract, and perhaps do something à la:

```
contract CoolSchool {
    mapping(string => string) public books; // ISBN => Book title
    mapping(string => string[]) public readers; // Reader name => ISBNs read

    constructor() {
        _loadBooks();
    }

    function addBook(string memory isbn, string memory title) public {
        require(!_isEmpty(isbn), "isbn is required");
        require(!_isEmpty(title), "title is required");
        books[isbn] = title;
    }

    function addReadBook(string memory reader, string memory isbn) public {
        string[] storage read = readers[reader];
        require(!_isEmpty(books[isbn]), "unknown book");
        read.push(isbn);
    }

    function _loadBooks() private {
        books["0333791037"] = "The Great Gatsby";
        books["0684833395"] = "Catch-22";
        books["9780451524935"] = "1984";
    }

    function _isEmpty(string memory s) private pure returns (bool) {
        return bytes(s).length == 0;
    }
}
```